# Subsetting and plotting data by TimeStamp

Tags: r

I have a data.frame P1 (5000rows x 4cols) and would like to save the subset of data in columns 2,3 and 4 when the time-stamp in column 1 falls into a set range determined by a vector TimeStamp (in seconds).

E.g. put all values in columns 2, 3, and 4  into a new data.frame and call each section of data: Condition.1.P1, Condition.2.P1, etc.

The reason I'd like to label separately as I have 35 versions of P1 (P2, P3, P33, etc) and need to be able to melt them together to plot them.

```
dput(TimeStamp)
c(18, 138, 438, 678, 798, 1278, 1578, 1878, 2178)


dput(head(P1))
structure(list(Time = c(0, 5, 100, 200, 500, 1200), SkinTemp = c(27.781, 
27.78, 27.779, 27.779, 27.778, 27.777), HeartRate = c(70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70), RespirationRate = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), .Names = c("Time", 
"SkinTemp", "HeartRate", "RespirationRate"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to seperate the data by the timestamp range and put it in a list? Than this might be what you are looking for:

```
TimeStamp <- c(18, 138, 438, 678, 798, 1278, 1578, 1878, 2178)

dat <- structure(list(Time = c(0, 5, 100, 200, 500, 1200), SkinTemp =(27.781, 
27.78, 27.779, 27.779, 27.778, 27.777), HeartRate = c(70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70), RespirationRate = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), .Names = c ("Time", 
"SkinTemp", "HeartRate", "RespirationRate"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

dat$Segment <- cut(dat$Time,c(-Inf,TimeStamp))
split(dat,dat$Segment)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this gives me it in the correct format. How do I only plot one variable between  TimeStamp 138 and 438 now that it's in this format? plot(split(dat,dat$Segment)$`(138,438]`) plots all variables

Comment: `plot(split(dat,dat$Segment)$`(138,438]`[,1:4])` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
P2 = data.frame(NA, NA, NA, NA) # Create empty data.frame
for (i in 1:length(ts)){
    P3 = data.frame() # Create empty changing data.frame
    if (i == 1) {ts1 = 0} else {ts1 = ts[i-1]} #First time stamp starts at 0
    ts2 = ts[i]
    P3 = subset(P1, P1$Time > ts1 & P1$Time < ts2)[,c(2,3,4)] #Subset the columns and assign to P3
    if (nrow(P3) == 0){P3 = data.frame(NA, NA, NA)} #If the subset is empty, assign NA
    P3$TimeStamp = paste(ts1,ts2,sep="-") # Append TimeStamp to the P3
    colnames(P3) = colnames(P2) #Make sure column names are same to allow rbind
    P2 = rbind(P2,P3) #Append P3 to P2
}
P2 = P2[c(2:nrow(P2)),] #Remove the first row (that has NA)
colnames(P2) = c("SkinTemp", "HeartRate", "RespirationRate", "TimeStamp") #Provide column names)
rm(P3); rm(i); rm(ts1); rm(ts2) #Cleanup
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to do it for the time intervals in my vector TimeStamp?