# Subsetting data by Time-stamp or interval and id in R

Tags: r

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571350/subsetting-and-plotting-data-by-timestamp/41571555?noredirect=1#comment70350525_41571555) about subsetting data based on a TimeStamp for a single file and got a great answer. Now I have imported 29 files into one data.frame (*l2*) and given them ids from 1 to 29. I'd like to be able to subset the data in *l2* based on intervals in the data.frame *m*.

**My problem** is that each I need to split *l2* based on the interval in *m* and based on the column called *l2$id* (because the experiment wasn't synchronised).

E.g. For all values in l2$SkinTemp, l2$RespirationRate and l2$HeartRate with l2$id==1 i need to split them by **m$P1**. And so on for P2 for l2$id==2

```
dput(head(l2))
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), Time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), SkinTemp = c(27.781, 27.78, 27.779, 27.779, 27.778, 27.777
), HeartRate = c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70), RespirationRate = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), .Names = c("id", "Time", "SkinTemp", "HeartRate", 
"RespirationRate"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a data.frame (TimeStamp) which includes time intervals in seconds:

```
    dput(head(m))
structure(list(MARKER = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), P1 = c(18, 138, 438, 678, 798, 1278), P2 = c(1, 
121, 421, 541, 661, 1141), P3 = c(2, 122, 422, 542, 662, 1142
), P4 = c(70, 190, 490, 600, 730, 1170), P5 = c(76, 196, 496, 
616, 752, 1232), P6 = c(33, 153, 453, 595, 715, 1195), P7 = c(20, 
149, 449, 569, 777, 1257), P8 = c(100, 241, 541, 661, 819, 1319
), P9 = c(25, 145, 445, 583, 763, 1246), P10 = c(18, 141, 441, 
621, 801, 1281), P11 = c(70, 190, 490, 710, 830, 1310), P12 = c(35, 
155, 455, 635, 755, 1235), P13 = c(35, 155, 455, 575, 695, 1175
), P14 = c(37, 157, 517, 637, 774, 1254), P15 = c(18, 138, 378, 
498, 678, 1158), P16 = c(49, 169, 469, 589, 769, 1266), P17 = c(75, 
195, 520, 625, 805, 1295), P18 = c(20, 140, 440, 560, 740, 1227
), P19 = c(8, 144, 444, 564, 780, 1260), P20 = c(25, 147, 447, 
648, 768, 1248), P21 = c(47, 173, 467, 587, 707, 1187), P22 = c(28, 
148, 448, 568, 688, 1168), P23 = c(22, 142, 442, 562, 682, 1172
), P24 = c(52, 145, 452, 684, 804, 1284), P25 = c(11, 131, 431, 
618, 738, 1218), P26 = c(19, 139, 439, 619, 762, 1250), P27 = c(41, 
161, 465, 672, 792, 1272), P28 = c(63, 183, 487, 667, 787, 1267
), P29 = c(71, 195, 495, 675, 795, 1275), P30 = c(135, 255, 555, 
675, 795, 1275), P31 = c(561, 681, 981, 1101, 1303, 1701), P32 = c(15, 
135, 435, 555, 675, 1155), P33 = c(31, 151, 451, 571, 691, 1171
), P34 = c(10, 130, 430, 550, 670, 1150), P35 = c(35, 155, 455, 
695, 815, 1295)), .Names = c("MARKER", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", 
"P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P13", "P14", 
"P15", "P16", "P17", "P18", "P19", "P20", "P21", "P22", "P23", 
"P24", "P25", "P26", "P27", "P28", "P29", "P30", "P31", "P32", 
"P33", "P34", "P35"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This works for if i do it manually on one file

```
P1$Segment <- cut(l2$Time,c(-Inf,m$P1))
split(l2,P1$Segment)
```

Comment: The data throws an error `Error: object 'First' not found`

Comment: I put those in manually because they were NAs and I thought it might look better. I'll edit the question.

Comment: There are 35 "P" columns in `m` as well as a "MARKER" column. Doesn't seem to match up with the number 29. It also doesn't make sense to split values for temperature, RespirationRate, and heart rate all at the same breaks. They are measured on different numerical scales. I think you probably need to improve your description of the question and show a desired result.

Comment: @42- Thank you very for looking at this. There were supposed to be 35 participants in the experiment but some have not been input yet so I'm looking at P1-P29. I'd like to split the data by the columns in m for each different id in l2. I.e if l2$id==1 && l2$Time<m$P1[1] then split data, etc.

Comment: for the same `Id`, is each value of `P{i}` corresponding to a different column in `l2`?  and in that case, `l2` has 5 columns to be split (excluding `Id`) while the example `m` has 6 rows for each `P{i}`. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Base solution

Up front: your data seems incomplete as a full reproducible question
(e.g., only one unique `id`, all values of `m$MARKER` are `NA`, all
but one value in `l2` are invariant). I'll create a
similarly-structured dataset, hoping you can adjust the code to your
own data.

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 10
l2 <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:2, each = 5),
  Time = rep(c(11, 33, 55, 77, 99), times = 2),
  SkinTemp = runif(n, min = 27.7, max = 27.9),
  HeartRate = 60 + sample(30, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  RespirationRate = 5 + sample(10, size = n, replace = TRUE)
)
str(l2)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ id             : int  1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
#  $ Time           : num  11 33 55 77 99 11 33 55 77 99
#  $ SkinTemp       : num  27.9 27.9 27.8 27.9 27.8 ...
#  $ HeartRate      : num  74 82 89 68 74 89 90 64 75 77
#  $ RespirationRate: num  15 7 15 15 6 11 9 15 10 14
(m <- data.frame(
  MARKER = 1:3,
  P1 = c(18, 44, 135),
  P2 = c(1, 66, 105)
))
#   MARKER  P1  P2
# 1      1  18   1
# 2      2  44  66
# 3      3 135 105
```

Assign the `Segment` variable, grouped by `id`:

```
l2a <- do.call(rbind, by(l2, l2$id, function(x) {
  x$Segment <- cut(x$Time, c(-Inf, m[,paste0("P", x$id[1])]))
  x
}))
```

(The `do.call(rbind, ...)` is to ensure we end up with a data.frame; though not strictly required, it seems to make it a little easier to see the next step.

Now to split. If you want a "2+" variable split, the
second argument needs to be a list. Note the `drop` argument: if
unstated (default `FALSE`), then you will get all possible values of
the entire column within each `id` group; sometimes this is good,
sometimes not. In this example, it results in several empty (0 row) data.frames in the list. (I trimmed the output for this page.)

```
str( split(l2a, list(l2a$id, l2a$Segment), drop = TRUE) )
# List of 5
#  $ 1.(-Inf,18]:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  6 variables:
#   ..$ id             : int 1
#   ..$ Time           : num 11
#   ..$ SkinTemp       : num 27.9
#   ..$ HeartRate      : num 74
#   ..$ RespirationRate: num 15
#   ..$ Segment        : Factor w/ 6 levels "(-Inf,18]","(18,44]",..: 1
#  $ 1.(18,44]  :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ 1.(44,135] :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ 2.(1,66]   :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ 2.(66,105] :'data.frame':  2 obs. of  6 variables:
```

### `factor`s returned from `cut`

Completely a personal preference, but I prefer indices out of `cut` instead of `factor`s or `character`s. You can do `cut(..., labels = FALSE)` to get `integer`s. Recall that values outside of the cut range will be `NA` (not new).

### "long" versus "wide" markers

If your data.frame `m` is certainly fixed then you can get away with this, but it will of course get very "wide" if you have more respondents. Many data-bubbas prefer to work in "long" formats. In this contrived example it does not buy you a lot, but as you formalize the data structures with which you work (e.g., databases, variable-length groupings, etc), then you may benefit from using the "long" format.

```
library(tidyr)
m2 <- gather(m, id, TimeCut, -MARKER)
m2$id <- gsub("^P", "", m2$id)
m2
#   MARKER id TimeCut
# 1      1  1      18
# 2      2  1      44
# 3      3  1     135
# 4      1  2       1
# 5      2  2      66
# 6      3  2     105
```

Your first split would then be something like:

```
l2b <- do.call(rbind, by(l2, l2$id, function(x) {
  x$Segment <- cut(x$Time, c(-Inf, subset(m2, id == x$id[1])$TimeCut))
  x
}))
```

(Not really improved here, remember I said something like "if your data gets bigger/variant/...").

One example of why I would work like this: often I'm working with data that others are providing in a database. This can be something formal such as SQL Server or PostgreSQL, or a little simpler such as SQLite. In any case, having a variable-width column (such as your `m`) is kind of a pain for databases: though you can add columns, that is most certainly not the recommended method. Knowing some SQL and ways to pass it back/forth is one feather in the cap of a flexible data-science toolkit. (Sorry, I'll get off the soapbox here.)

### `dplyr`

Some prefer the readability of more tools in the `tidyverse`. Here's the same thing, but in `dplyr`-speak:

```
library(dplyr)
l2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # mutate( Segment = cut(Time, c(-Inf, subset(m2, id == id[1])$TimeCut))) %>%
  mutate( Segment = cut(Time, c(-Inf, m2$TimeCut[m2[["id"]] == id[1]])) ) %>%
  group_by(id, Segment) %>%
  do({
    dat <- .
    # do something with dat
    dat
  })
# Source: local data frame [10 x 6]
# Groups: id, Segment [5]
#       id  Time SkinTemp HeartRate RespirationRate   Segment
#    <int> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>    <fctr>
# 1      1    11 27.88296        74              15 (-Inf,18]
# 2      1    33 27.88742        82               7   (18,44]
# 3      1    55 27.75723        89              15  (44,135]
# 4      1    77 27.86609        68              15  (44,135]
# 5      1    99 27.82835        74               6  (44,135]
# 6      2    11 27.80382        89              11    (1,66]
# 7      2    33 27.84732        90               9    (1,66]
# 8      2    55 27.72693        64              15    (1,66]
# 9      2    77 27.83140        75              10  (66,105]
# 10     2    99 27.84101        77              14  (66,105]
```

Though it doesn't *look* split in the result shown, notice the `Groups: id, Segment [5]`, which says that most `dplyr` functions on that data will do things once per grouping. If you replace `# do something with dat` with `browser()` and run it, you can play around with one group at a time to see how the `do()` block works.

Note that you must either return a data.frame (using `do({...})`) or assign it to a variable (with `do(newvar = {...})`). This latter choice may then suggest the use of `unnest()`, depending on what you do.

(BTW: `dplyr` can also work really with with databases. If you read any of Hadley's books, tutorials, vignettes, or other docs, you'll probably run across him recommending "long" over "wide", so it's almost "enforced".)

**Edit:**

A comment asked if it is possible to associate each row with the row (`MARKER`) that made the match. Here's a modification to the `dplyr` solution that adds the row index as well as the lower/upper bounds.

```
l2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # mutate( Segment = cut(Time, c(-Inf, subset(m2, id == id[1])$TimeCut))) %>%
  mutate(
    Segment = cut(Time, c(-Inf, m2$TimeCut[m2[["id"]] == id[1]]), labels = FALSE),
    TimeLower = c(-Inf, m2$TimeCut)[Segment],
    TimeUpper = c(-Inf, m2$TimeCut)[1+Segment]
  ) %>%
  group_by(id, Segment) %>%
  do({
    dat <- .
    # do something with dat
    dat
  })
# Source: local data frame [10 x 8]
# Groups: id, Segment [5]
#       id  Time SkinTemp HeartRate RespirationRate Segment TimeLower TimeUpper
#    <int> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1      1    11 27.88296        74              15       1      -Inf        18
# 2      1    33 27.88742        82               7       2        18        44
# 3      1    55 27.75723        89              15       3        44       135
# 4      1    77 27.86609        68              15       3        44       135
# 5      1    99 27.82835        74               6       3        44       135
# 6      2    11 27.80382        89              11       2        18        44
# 7      2    33 27.84732        90               9       2        18        44
# 8      2    55 27.72693        64              15       2        18        44
# 9      2    77 27.83140        75              10       3        44       135
# 10     2    99 27.84101        77              14       3        44       135
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is fabulous! I really appreciate the detail you have provided too! There is one small nuance that I've noticed: Eventually I'd like to plot the data based on `id` and `segment`. For example I'd like to plot all Respiration rates coloured by id between a certain interval. But since each row value in m is different this won't work because the intervals don't match up. Is it possible to label the segments 1,2,3,4 etc for each id instead of their numeric value? If so that would be AMAZING!

Comment: That's a fantastic update, thank you! I have used dplyr a little and find it really versatile. What does the %>% mean?

Comment: The `%>%` is the "pipe operator", imported from the `magrittr` package. Think of it as being similar to the shell `|` pipe, where the output data from the func to the left is being passed as the first option to the func on the right. For instance, `func1(x,a=1) %>% func2(b=2)` is equivalent to `func2(func2(x, a=1), b=2)`, and some argue the former is more readable.